# Creating transparent PNG image from mask and input image using CPP and OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to use the following code for generating a transparent PNG:
my original image is "frame":

```
                        cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(frame.size(), CV_8U);
                        cv::drawContours(mask, std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>>{ maxAreaContour }, -1, cv::Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);
                        cv::Mat bframe = cv::Mat::zeros(frame.size(),CV_8UC4);
                        bframe=cv::Scalar(255,255,255,0);
                        frame.copyTo(bframe, mask);
                        cv::namedWindow("frg", 0);
                        cv::imshow("frg", bframe);
                        cv::namedWindow("mask", 0);
                        cv::imshow("mask", mask);
```

[image: Original Image]

[image: mask]

And from some reason, I am not able to save the original image with transparent background, i keep get the black background when show as the "bframe" image output
any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: You need to show it or save as PNG?

Comment: save it as PNG, but even when showing it i wasnt able to get the transparent background

Comment: try `frame.copyTo(bframe, 255-mask);` instead, since your mask is the foreground object, right? If want to keep the original colors and just add the alpha channel, use split and merge or iterate over all pixels manually

Comment: instead of imshow, use imwrite as png to test the transparency. OpenCV doesn't render alpha channel at all.

Comment: @user1322801 If you edit the question and learn how to resize your images (using markdown) to something more visually pleasant, I will upvote your question.

Answer (score 1):

`cv::imshow` strips out the alpha chanel, so you need to blend image before showing.(i.e. choosing colour or texture to represent background pixels and merge it with your image)

But if you only need to save it, just save it as .png; btw you can set compression params for PNG as:

```
    vector<int> compression_params;
    compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
    compression_params.push_back(9); //Compression level

    try {
        imwrite("bframe.png", bframe, compression_params);
    }
    catch (runtime_error& ex) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Exception converting image to PNG format: %s\n", ex.what());
        return 1;
    }
```

Ref:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html